# when retrieving connection showing closed connection error

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-jdbc, hikaricp

I am intermittently seeing closed connection error when I create a prepared statement  any clue what the issue is here ?

Below is how  I get the connection and preparestatement

```
ConnectionManager.getConnection();
con.preparestatement(" select * from my_table ");
```

Below is the config for HikariCP:

```
<bean id="hikariConfig" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariConfig">
    <property name="poolName" value="my-pool" />
    <property name="registerMbeans" value="true" />
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${my.dbDriverClassName}" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${my.dbConnectionUrl}" />
    <property name="username" value="${my.dbUserName}" />
    <property name="password" value="${my.dbPassword}" />
     <property name="connectionTestQuery" value="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL" />
    <property name="maximumPoolSize" value="100" />
    <property name="minimumIdle" value="10" />
    <property name="leakDetectionThreshold" value="120000" />
    <property name="maxLifetime" value="600000" />
    <property name="idleTimeout" value="60000" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource" destroy- 
  method="close">
    <constructor-arg ref="hikariConfig" />
</bean>

<bean  
 class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate"
       c:dataSource-ref="dataSource"  />

<bean  id="jdbcTransactionManager" 
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
       p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"/>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="jdbcTransactionManager"/>

<bean id="jdbcTemplate"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

pastebin for ConnectionManager https://pastebin.com/aqNKtwaH

Comment: Can you show code? are there other errors or leak warnings?

Comment: @user7294900 Yes, I see connection leak error

Comment: Can you add the stacktrace?

Comment: in the pastebin https://pastebin.com/UUEfayzJ  I see error on line 33

Comment: How your code compiled? `ResultSet  = null;` and
         `Product=null;`?

Comment: @user7294900 please check this https://pastebin.com/p6ZkDpRs error on line 8, rest controller calls service and service calls dao. This is not the actual code, but example of actual code with changed method name and parameters

Comment: This is a different question, please ask a new question with enough details. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: but the core issue is same not a different one, its the same Closed connection error

Answer (score 0):

Notice that Hikari's leak warning stacktrace prints **after** leak happened, when there are no connections are available in pool, so your code can be leaking from a different method

There's a issue with your code:

> ```
> }finally{
>  rs.close();
> pst.close();
>   con.close();          
> }
> ```

If `rs` or `pst` are null `conn` won't be closed and you will have a leak

Add null check before calling `close()` method or use try with resources

Comment: I agree with using null check for the connection, but why would I see the Closed Connection on line 33 ?

Comment: @Ayub the leak warning happens **after** the leak occurred, so leak can happen in different code, but leak catch in line 33 when there are no more connection available in pool

Comment: ah ok, thanx for the clues, will try and let you know

Comment: why intermittent Closed Connection error ? shouldn't it fail all requests once Closed Connection error is thrown for first time. If there are no more connections available in the pool how are other requests being served ?

Comment: I have implemented null check before close but that does not seem to stop the Closed Connection message, I do not see the connection leak error